# When does a practice become a minhag?

Tags: minhag

What are the criterion for a practice to become a minhag?  Just because we do something over and over does that make it a minhag?  Changing a minhag can be difficult but how does one actually get started in the first place?

Comment: Are you referring to individuals or a communal minhag?

Comment: Not sure it matters.  Trying to understand when something becomes a minhag.  If an individual or communty do the same thing over and over is it by default a minhag?